# 「限定モデル」... Limited edition? Special edition? etc

Tags: meaning

So throwing this phrase into GOOG Translate gives me "limited model", I know this phrase is used quite frequently in Japan, but thinking about it a bit realized I have never actually heard "limited model" used back stateside...

So would「限定モデル」be applicable to "limited edition" ("limited edition model"), "special edition" or something else like a nerfed edition?

Comment: It's Google製 not 和製. I'm not sure if this question is about Japanese or English.

Comment: @macraf Edited.

Comment: @Y12K, it varies depending on the context. Generally speaking, yes, "limited edition" is fine and makes more sense in English. (i.e. This model is a limited edition.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weblio has *limited model* as the translation for 限定モデル (from JST科学技術用語日英対訳辞書) or *special specificaiton model for limited sales* (from 英和対訳). As these don't sound natural to me, I turned to linguee.

From https://www.linguee.com/english-japanese/search?source=auto&query=%E9%99%90%E5%AE%9A%E3%83%A2%E3%83%87%E3%83%AB.

ショパールの150周年を記念して、同社の遺産に敬意を表して製作されたL.U.C 1937の限定モデルが発表されました

For Chopard’s 150th anniversary, the
Manufacture launched a limited edition of the L.U.C 1937 model – a mechanical tribute to the company’s watchmaking heritage.

ジョゼフ・シドローヴィッツ氏の卓越したデザインと木工技術は、カスタムメイドのスタインウェ イ 限定モデル の 制 作には欠かせません

are essential in meeting the design and manufacturing challenges of creating
Steinway custom and limited edition pianos

As these examples show, "limited edition" is a normal translation in context.

Google Translate is often unreliable and sometimes downright misleading or nonsensical. I wouldn't rely on it too much for Japanese if it can be avoided.

Comment: Am aware how unreliable Google Translate is at conveying context, but gotta start somewhere. Also saw the weblio one and it just seemed weird.